# html form with white fields to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I don't understand what is the correct way to pass the html form fields to mysql database in case one of the fields is empty.

I have this html:

```
<form name="formName" method="POST" action="" onsubmit="registra();">
  <label for="datetime1">datetime one</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="datetime1" name="datetime1">
  <label for="datetime2">datetime two</label>
  <input type="datetime-local" id="datetime2" name="datetime2">
  <button type="submit">Salva</button>
</form>

<script>
function registra() {
  var datetime1 = document.forms['formName']['datetime1'].value;
  datetime1 = new Date(datetime1).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
  var datetime2 = document.forms['formName']['datetime2'].value;
  datetime2 = new Date(datetime1).toISOString().slice(0, 19).replace('T', ' ');
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "./functions.php",
    data: {
      action: 'registraForm',
      id: <?php echo $id; ?>,
      datetime1: datetime1,
      datetime2: datetime2
    }
  }).done(function( response ) {
    alert( response );
  });
}
</script>
```

And this php:

```
<?php
/* AJAX */
if(isset($_POST['action']) && !empty($_POST['action'])) {
  $action = $_POST['action'];
  switch($action) {
    case 'registraForm' : registra_form();break;
  }
}


function registra_form() {
  $dbhost = "localhost";
  $dbuser = "user";
  $dbpass = "pass";
  $db = "db";
  $conn = new mysqli($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass,$db) or die("Connect failed: %s\n". $conn -> error);

  $id = $_POST['id'];
  $datetime1 = ($_POST['datetime1']?$_POST['datetime1']:NULL);
  $datetime2 = ($_POST['datetime2']?$_POST['datetime2']:NULL);

  if ( /* update mysql row */ ) {
    $sql = "UPDATE table SET datetime1='$datetime1', datetime2 = '$datetime2', WHERE id=$id";
  } else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table (id, datetime1, datetime2) VALUES ($id, '$datetime1', '$datetime2')";
  }
  if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo 'done!';
  } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
  }
  die();
  $conn -> close();
}
```

In the database both datetime1 and datetime2 are set as timestamp type with default null.

If both datetime1 and datetime2 are filled, the registration is successful. If instead one of the two fields of the form is not filled I receive a sql syntax error.
Something like `error: UPDATE table SET datetime1='2020-04-17 11:06:00', datetime2='' WHERE id=5 Incorrect datetime value:'' for column db.table.datetime2 at row 2`

I think this is the problem `$datetime2 = ($_POST['datetime2']?$_POST['datetime2']:NULL);` but I don't know how to solve it.

Thanks
Fosco

Comment: You're trying to use a ternary operator but not using it the right way. Consult the manual https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Well the error message tells all... It clearly states that you are not providing the correct value for your datetime fields. Clearly NULL is invalid, hence the error. So what are your schema settings in your table for datetime1 and datetime2?

Comment: Sorry @TimBrownlaw, I edited the question. Both datetime1 and datetime2 are set as timestamp type with default null.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I just saw what you saw... takes a while sometimes...

Comment: Just wanted to know what results you got when you tried the following directly into phpmyadmin or whatever you use... 1. SET datetime1='2020-04-17 11:06:00', datetime2='NULL' WHERE id=5 and 2. SET datetime1='2020-04-17 11:06:00', datetime2=NULL WHERE id=5. 1. has NULL in quotes and 2 does not. You can fill in the rest of the SQL Statements to make them correct.

Comment: The problem is exactly that one: the only one that works is the second case. The 'NULL' case gives me this error: Incorrect datetime value: 'NULL' for column `db`.`table`.`datetime2` at row 2. But I need datetime2 = '$datetime2' to pass the correct date format when the field is not empty

Comment: Well of course 'NULL' is a string and NULL is the actual NULL constant, so what you are seeing is correct (you can fix that in your ternary and update/insert statements). But we aint got that far yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this is "an answer" and not a pretty one, based upon your supplied code/issue.

Personally I would not code it this way, but we cannot give tutorials on here.
This is more a demonstration on how to go about working something out, without all the in between bits.

This is an example. Test Code (something we should learn to write), I used to test getting the correct SQL Statements.

```
function test_datetime_sql()
{
    $_POST['datetime1'] = '';
    $_POST['datetime2'] = '2020-04-17 11:06:00';

    // There must be a more elegant way to do this    
    $datetime1 = $_POST['datetime1']?"'".$_POST['datetime1']."'":'NULL';
    $datetime2 = $_POST['datetime2']?"'".$_POST['datetime2']."'":'NULL';

    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'LINE: '. __LINE__. ' Module '.__CLASS__.'<br>';
    var_dump($datetime1);
    echo '</pre>';

    echo '<pre>';
    echo 'LINE: '. __LINE__. ' Module '.__CLASS__.'<br>';
    var_dump($datetime2);
    echo '</pre>';

    $id = 5;

    $sql = "UPDATE table SET 
                datetime1 = $datetime1,
                datetime2 = $datetime2, 
                    WHERE id=$id";

    var_dump($sql); // What SQL do we get

}
```

Give that a try by generating the SQL and testing it.

**Notice that its a change to the Ternary AND the SQL statement** - notice the lack of '' in the `$sql` for datetime1 and datetime2 as they are generated in the ternary.

What is happening here is if it is a "Not Empty" Value, it's getting wrapped in '' to make it a string.
The same occurs with NULL

I strongly suggest you copy and paste this somewhere and play with it to see what happens.

In your original code, when you set `$datetime1` as NULL it appears in your SQL as `$datetime1 = ''` and NOT as `$datetime1 = NULL` ( Not the string 'NULL' ).

Comment: Thanks TimBrownlaw, this works. Can I ask you for a link where I can learn what would be the right way to write this code? I would like to write it in the best possible way.